# Splitting the ranges using DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

I have an application that deals with reporting time for tasks. In this application, you can make corrections to the reported tasks. I have several scenarios to consider among others:

> Scenario 1 You want to divide the work period 10:00 - 14:00 in half
>   because you have forgotten to switch tasks Introduces the correction
>   with a new task, from 12:00 - 14:00. The correction of the home
>   working time is made automatically.
>
> Scenario 2: The user worked from 09:00 - 17:00 on one task, but
>   remembered that from 11:00 - 12:00 he should report on something
>   else. Makes the correction for another task between 11:00 and 12:00.
>   The home working period is automatically divided into two periods 9:00
>   - 11:00 and 12:00 - 17:00.
>
> Scenario 3 The operator has between 09:00-11:00 on task A
>   between 11:00-17:00 on task B The user wants to make the
>   correction in 10-12 time by entering task C The home working times of
>   Tasks A and B are corrected for Tasks C
>
> Scenario 4 The user was working on task A between 10:00 and 12:00.
>   User confused tasks and logged in time not for this task The user
>   changes the name of the task A to B  leaving the home time 10:00-12:00

In my opinion, the most complicated scenarios are 2 and 3, and my question is how easy it will be to achieve these scenarios. Generally, I'm talking about a nice idea to recalculate it. Has anyone ever had a similar problem and is able to share it with me or has you ideas for it?

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: I have no solution yet. At the moment I'm looking for some solution to these scenarios, it doesn't necessarily have to be a ready-made code, I'm more interested in discussing this problem and some of the possibilities.